# How to import all variables from other package?

Tags: perl

I have package with globals:

```
package Constants;

use strict;
use warnings;    

use Exporter qw( import );
use Exporter ();
use vars qw(@ISA @EXPORT_OK);
@ISA       = qw(Exporter);
@EXPORT_OK = qw(@A %B, $C, foo);

our %B = (id  => 0, desc => "AF :: BUILD SUCCEEDED");        
our @A = (
    "Undefined symbols for architecture",
    "BUILD FAILED"
);
our  $C = "blablabla";

sub foo(){}

1;
```

in other Perl file I can use this package as:

```
use FindBin qw($RealBin);
use lib $RealBin;    

use Constants qw(@A %B, $C, foo);
```

It will work.

I want to change a bit the package usage like:

```
use Constants;
```

So logically the usage should be:

```
Constants::@A;  # I get an error
Constants::%B;  # I get an error
Constants::$C;  # I get an error
```

This approach works with methods, for example:

```
Constants::foo(); # works!!
```

So how I can use `@A %B $C` without calling chain them into `qw(@A %B $C)`?

Comment: Note that the newest and best way to acquire an `import` method is to *import* it from `Exporter`. That is what you have done with the statement `use Exporter qw( import )`. The old-fashioned way is to use Perl's *inheritance* mechanism, and you have also implemented that with `@ISA = qw(Exporter)`. You shouldn't be using both methods at the same time, so `@ISA` should remain empty. It also probably better to use `our` instead of `use vars`, so you can define `@EXPORT_OK` using `our @EXPORT_OK = qw(@A %B, $C, foo)` and drop the `use vars` statement.

Comment: Finally, there is no need to load `Exporter` twice, so you can also remove `use Exporter ()`. These measures will substantially tidy your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The sigil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigil_(computer_programming)) (`$`, `@` or `%`) needs to go first when using fully qualified variable names.

```
@Constants::A; 
%Constants::B; 
$Constants::C;
```

This is explained in the first parts of [perlsyn](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html).

You might have seen that in other packages, like [Data::Dumper](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper), which allows you [to configure it with its package variables](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper#Configuration-Variables-or-Methods).

```
use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Indent = 0;
```

In your package you can use `$C`, which simply has an empty namespace, so the current one is assumed.

```
$           foo  # namespace is nothing
$Constants::foo  # namespace is Constants::
```

It works with functions (what you're showing is not a method because there is no OOP involved, a method call would be `Constants->foo`) because those usually have no sigil. You could do `&Constants::foo()`, which uses the `&` to turn off any prototypes, but please don't do that unless you know what you're doing.

There is one more sigil `*` for typeglobs. The same rules apply for it.

---

The last sentence of your question is confusing.

> [...] without calling chain them into qw(@A %B $C)?

I think you mean *importing* them. That's what the Exporter lets you do when you put the names into `@EXPORT_OK`. The list of names you pass to `use Constants` tells Exporter which symbols it should install into your namespace.

It then puts something like a pointer into your namespace that says your `$C` refers to the same thing as `$Constants::C`.

When you declare package variables with `our` or `use vars` (let's consider them equivalent for the scope of this answer), they are always accessible from the outside. You just need to use the fully qualified package name.

Importing them into your own namespace is just a convenience. You could do it yourself too.

```
use Constants (); # the empty list explicitly imports nothing
*C = \$Constants::C;
```

You just made your own import. But you probably don't want to do that.

Answer (score -2):

```
package Constants;

use strict;

use warnings;

use Exporter;

our @ISA        = qw(Exporter);

our @EXPORT     = qw(@A %B $C foo); # always exports these to main::

our %B = (id  => 0, desc => "AF :: BUILD SUCCEEDED");

our @A = (

    "Undefined symbols for architecture",

    "BUILD FAILED"

);

our  $C = "blablabla";

sub foo(){}

1;
```